# Proof for this relation regarding complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

This is what I have to prove :

Re($z_1z_2$) = Re($z_1$)Re($z_2$) - Im($z_1$)Im($z_2$).

I have two complex numbers : $z_1$ and $z_2$. Can anyone give at least some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try...?

$$
(a+bi)\cdot(c+di) = \dots
$$